# Checked ToolStrip Submenu Items

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to create a menu in VB.Net where one item in the menu has a submenu that sprouts off to the side when the user hovers over it.  In other words, a completely ordinary submenu that everyone's used a million times.

My main menu items are of class ToolStripMenuItem.  I can get close to the behavior I want by using the item's "DropDown" member.  This creates the submenu behavior correctly, but I also need to be able to check and uncheck the items in the submenu.  I've set the submenu items' "CheckOnClick" property to True, but checkboxes are still not displayed when I run the program.

Is it possible to get this behavior?  Is it possible with ToolStripMenuItem?

Here's the code I currently have, which gets close, but doesn't give me checkboxes:

```
Dim mainItem As ToolStripMenuItem = New ToolStripMenuItem()
mainItem.Text = "Click For Submenu"

Dim subMenu As ToolStripDropDown = New ToolStripDropDown()
For Each item As ToolStripMenuItem In listOfItems
  item.CheckOnClick = True
  subMenu.Items.Add(item)
Next

mainItem.DropDown = subMenu
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try getting rid of that subMenu variable and change the code this way:

```
For Each mi As ToolStripMenuItem In listOfItems
  mi.CheckOnClick = True
  mainItem.DropDownItems.Add(mi)
Next
```

Comment: That did it! I don't know why this easy answer was so hard to find. Thanks!